# Array modification in loop

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, types

I'm working on a command-line application. The first array (which is called firstArray, yes) is a result of user input via readLine(), all of its elements is Double. Now I have to create a second array with results of calculations applied to my first array. Some of results is NaN, cause of trigonometric calculations. I need to change all the NaNs to string, but I get the error "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Double'". How to solve this problem?

```
func calcLn () -> [Double] {

var calculatedArray = [Double]()

for item in firstArray {
    var result = log(Double((-100))/(cos(item)))
    calculatedArray.append(result)
}

for index in 0..<calculatedArray.count {
    if calculatedArray[index].isNaN {
    calculatedArray[index] = String("can't calculate")
```

Comment: A `String` is not a `Double` and cannot be saved as such. `Double.NaN` is a way to let you as a developer know no value is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array can only store one type of stuff. `calculatedArray` can only store `Double`s, so you can't set its elements to `String`s.

You can create a new array called `outputArray` that can store strings, and convert all the doubles to strings:

```
var outputArray = [String]()
for index in 0..<calculatedArray.count {
    if calculatedArray[index].isNaN {
        outputArray.append("can't calculate")
    } else {
        outputArray.append("\(calculatedArray[index])")
    }
}
```

Your `calcLn` method returns a `[Double]`, but it seems like you want to return `outputArray`. If that's the case, you need to change its signature to return `[String]`.

Note that you can do array transformations with `map`. Here is a shorter version of your code:

```
func calcLn () -> [String] {
    let calculatedArray = firstArray.map { log(100.0/cos($0)) }
    let outputStringsArray = calculatedArray.map { $0.isNaN ? "can't calculate" : "\($0)" }

    return outputStringsArray
}
```